# Winedt 6.0 toc tree and window view automation?

Tags: editors, winedt

I have several questions concerning possible features/configurations I am searching for in Winedt6.

I'd like to do the following stuff but I even don't know if this is possible or if there are respective options:

1. I'd like the tex tree to be built automatically all the time. That is, I don't want to click any button in order to refresh the tree.
2. The TOC tree should show the numbering of the sections etc.
3. I'd like to clone my window such that I can see and edit the very same file in two views/panes/windows in parallel/simultaneously.
4. I want the TOC tree to expand till the level of sections by default.
5. If I edit a file opened in Winedt6.0 with another editor, I want Winedt to update its Window silently without asking me if it should show the changes made externally.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some WinEdt macro programming (in version 5.5, but I don't think it's changed much since then).  In any case, that's the way to go, even though its macro programming language is pretty awful.  However, it does have DDE, and so you can have an external program issue commands to WinEdt.  This is similar to, but more powerful than, the commands issued from the preview when doing an inverse search.

For example, if WinEdt does not have a 'execute every 5 seconds' command, you could fake one by using an external process to send a request by DDE every 5 seconds.

You can get help on the basic WinEdt commands from the main menu bar, under Help or Macros, as I recall.  I hope this gets you going on your problem, because I don't think they'll be an off-the-shelf solution.

Another place to ask for help is usually friendly and helpful [WinEdt mailing list](http://winedt.com/support.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's helpful. I thought there might be a quick solution to it. Not sure if I manage to write the scripts. Let's see.